# Should we have an eclipse tag?

Tags: discussion, retagging

[What Blessing Does One Make on a Solar Eclipse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16354/)

[Eclipse of the moon, bad sign for the Jews](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4756/)

[Are there any sages who have written about experiencing a total solar eclipse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82326/)

[Why make a bracha on an earthquake but not on an eclipse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16877/)

[Parameters of the bad omen for eclipses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84291/)

[Can there be an early 'Tzes HaChochavim' due to an eclipse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32056/)

[Is there any evidence that Chazal knew what caused eclipses?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84829/)

[Good and Bad Omen - on something that can be calculated in advance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16891/)

With so many questions on eclipses, is it worth it to make an [eclipse](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) tag and go back and edit all of them? Or should we just stick with some combination of [astronomy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy), [natural-phenomenon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-phenomenon), [molad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molad), [rosh-chodesh-new-month](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosh-chodesh-new-month), et cetera? If we would add a new tag, I presume we would just have one tag to cover both solar and lunar eclipses?

Answer (score 3):

What would such a tag add which isn't already covered by the single word search term "eclipse"? Without a description of such an addition, I'd oppose such a tag.

Comment: Is that not true of any tag?

Comment: No,  it is not true of any tag. Consider [tag:parashas-yisro]